# how do i open a file from a html application using window_onload

Tags: html, vbscript, hta

I have this script in my hta application between `</head>` and `<body>`.

And it does work: it resizes and opens the wav files. But before it opens the wav files, I want it to load a file kind of like an ad popup if you will that will open as another hta window. How would I add the necessary lines of code to make it open say ad.hta before playing the .wav files?

```
<script language="VBScript">
Sub Window_OnLoad
Dim width,height
width=470
height=400
self.ResizeTo width,height
Set objVoice = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
Set objFile = CreateObject("SAPI.SpFileStream.1")
objFile.Open "111(2).wav"
objVoice.Speakstream objFile
Set objVoice = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
Set objFile = CreateObject("SAPI.SpFileStream.1")
objFile.Open "11537.wav"
objVoice.Speakstream objFile
End Sub
</script>
```

I have tried this:

```
Const NORMAL_WINDOW = 1
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "notepad.exe", "test.txt", , , NORMAL_WINDOW
```

Putting that just after the

```
self.ResizeTo width,height
```

The resulting action is in this order:

Program Opens,

Error continue running scripts shows

Text file opens

Audio Plays

But the program wont do what its supposed to do after that.
My text to speech function breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out
i did have to use

```
Const NORMAL_WINDOW = 1
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "notepad.exe", "test.txt", , , NORMAL_WINDOW
```

Got it working